# Angular: should I unsubscribe from switchMap

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've got the following component:

```
@Component({...})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  destroy$ = new Subject();
  update$ = new Subject();

  result: Result;

  constructor(service: Service) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    update$.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.destroy$),
      switchMap(() => this.service.get())
    ).subscribe(result => this.result = result);

    this.refresh();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }

  refresh() {
    this.update$.next();
  }

}
```

Is this approach correct? Or should I call `takeUntil(this.destroy$)` after `switchMap`?

```
update$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.service.get()),
  takeUntil(this.destroy$)
).subscribe(result => this.result = result);
```

Or should I call it twice?

```
update$.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destroy$),
  switchMap(() => this.service.get()),
  takeUntil(this.destroy$)
).subscribe(result => this.result = result);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The cleanest way is to call `takeUntil` after `switchMap`.

```
update$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.service.get()),
  takeUntil(this.destroy$)
).subscribe(result => this.result = result);
```

This will prevent any emissions to the subscription. If you add `takeUntil` before, the `switchMap` subscription will emit values until the observable returned by the `project` function completes, which may be never (depending on your service code).

It is not necessary to call `takeUntil` both before and after `switchMap`, because the `switchMap` unsubscribes from the source observable (everything before `switchMap`) when itself it is unsubscribed from.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would want `takeUntil` should be the last operator. In your case this is the correct approach:

```
update$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.service.get()),
  takeUntil(this.destroy$)
).subscribe(result => this.result = result);
```

Comment: Will it unsubscribe from both subject and service result?

Comment: Yes, it will unsubscribe form both